# keyboard shortcut for terminal opens and instantly closes terminal (konsole)

Tags: terminal, konsole

After upgrading to latest Kubuntu 15.04 my keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> no longer works. The Konsole window opens and instantly shuts down. Different keybindings don't work either. Other shortcuts like ctrl alt F for Firefox works fine.

Any tips?

edit: I managed to capture the message in displays right after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and before closing the window.
[image: Fig1]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me after Ubuntu and OSX upgrades.

A possible culprit and the reason for mine was that something in one of your "dot" profile files is no longer compatible.

So one option is to open/examine your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files, if they exist, and possible start commenting out stuff to see where the issue is.

Of course if you normally use a command line editor you will have to switch to another (probably gui editor) to make that change.

I'd avoid rebooting while you figure this out as you might actually then not be able to login at all.  This has happened to me.  Only the fact that I had another account with minimal settings (but a regular thus privileged enough) account) that saved me (i had to su and edit my dotfiles from that!).

Comment: .bash_profile doesnt exist and commenting .bashrc didnt help (from what i understood it contains mostly configs on "pretty and colourful terminal"). I edited in a screenshot of the event if that would help